# How to make gdb step-into operation in standard library C/C++ function?

Tags: c++, c, gdb

Recently I have faced an interesting problem. When I use gdb for code search, I can move inside any function which I defined, by step-into. But when I try to do it for standard C function (e.g printf() ) I see only binary form of source code.

How can I ask gdb to show human-readable source code? I am very interested in the work of standard functions.Thank you!

Comment: Install debuginfo for the c library

Comment: Depending on your system you need either to link the against debug-library or link against a library with debug symbols.

Comment: What is your OS? Installing libc debug symbols should be enough for what you want.

Comment: I use Linux, Ubuntu.

Comment: Since you're using Ubuntu, you likely already have debuginfo installed, but not the C library's source code. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48278881/gdb-complaining-about-missing-raise-c/48287761#48287761 for how to install that.

Answer (score 4):

You have to:

- Install the debug versions of the standard C and C++ libraries
- Tell the compiler to link against those versions

If you are on Linux and have GCC as your compiler, you can look up [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162513/how-do-i-tell-gcc-or-ld-to-link-against-debug-versions-of-the-standard-c-and-c) about how to do the second bullet above.